# What is wrong with my NetBeans editor?

Tags: netbeans

[image]

It adds a character to each line on moving to next line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing is wrong. That's a visual display of the newline character.

To turn if off use "View -> Show Non-printable Characters"